# Data objects conversion - instance method vs static method

Tags: java, static-methods, data-conversion

Assume there are two objects, ex. one represents public API (JSON) and other that represents model (JPA entity). They have some differences but most of the time fields are common.

```
class A {
    String name;
}

class B {
    String name;
}
```

Note that I keep these classes extremely simple for simplicity.

We have to convert one into another to make this design work properly.

On one hand we have instance methods. This seems to be intuitive approach. We already have an object so instance method seems to be logical solution. Access to fields is easy. It is also easy to read and understand the code. It ties one object to another, but they are meant to be a pair anyway.

```
static class A {
    String name;

    B toB() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setName(name);
        return b;
    }
}
```

The other approach is using static method. This seems to be more like a builder pattern. Object is built based on dependencies. Conversion method may be overloaded and use different input if needed, which adds flexibility. Yet, static method does not work well with OOP paradigm in general.

```
static class A {
    String name;

    static A from(B b) {
        A a = new A();
        a.setName(b.getName());
        return a;
    }
}
```

Now, there is a discussion among the team which approach is better in terms of OOP? Can any of them be considered as best practice? Or maybe there is other solution we should apply?

Simply speaking - what is the best approach in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are considering a situation when you have 2 classes that are similar (and partly interchangeable), but each one suits needs of a particular use-case better. This pretty much applies to "Array vs. Collection" topic. In JDK you get helper classes (utils) that facilitate the conversion: see `java.util.Arrays.asList()`.

That's the way I would go with - create a separate class to do the conversion. This way you do not couple the classes and you can further extend the conversion options (i.e. to class C), create "pluggable" conversion delegates, etc. Sounds like a far more flexible option to me.

Comment: That seems to be a good idea, and I already considered it, but if we're going to follow JDK examples, there is also a method `java.time.LocalDateTime#toLocalDate` or `java.util.stream.Stream#toArray`. JDK does not seem to be consistent about the design.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Particularly, `java.util.stream.Stream#toArray` is a way to process the result, not the stream itself. `Arrays#asList` on the other hand converts between 2 semantically similar classes. With some abstraction you can say that `Stream` is more then `Array`, but `List` is just a different implementation of `Array`. That's why the latter conversion is done by a util method while the first one is clearly a method of `Stream`.

Answer (score 0):

The second one will be good approach, since it follows design pattern and allows flexibility